# Error when building a production build

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I’m getting the following error when doing: `ionic build --prod`

> Error: ./src/pages/home/home.ngfactory.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../angularfire2/database' in '[myPath]\src\pages\home'
>   resolve '../../../angularfire2/database' in '[myPath]\src\pages\home'
>     using description file: [myPath]\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/home)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>     after using description file: [myPath]\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/home)
>       using description file: [myPath]\package.json (relative path: ./angularfire2/database)
>         no extension
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           [myPath]\angularfire2\database doesn't exist
>         .js
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           [myPath]\angularfire2\database.js doesn't exist
>         .ts
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           [myPath]\angularfire2\database.ts doesn't exist
>         as directory
>           [myPath]\angularfire2\database doesn't exist
>   [[myPath]\angularfire2\database]
>   [[myPath]\angularfire2\database.js]
>   [[myPath]\angularfire2\database.ts]
>   [[myPath]\angularfire2\database]
>    @ ./src/pages/home/home.ngfactory.js 41:0-59
>    @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
>    @ ./src/app/main.ts,./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../angularfire2/database' in '[myPath]\src\app'
>   resolve '../../angularfire2/database' in '[myPath]\src\app'
>     using description file: [myPath]\package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>     after using description file: [myPath]\package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
>       using description file: [myPath]\package.json (relative path: ./angularfire2/database)
>         no extension
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           [myPath]\angularfire2\database doesn't exist
>         .js
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           [myPath]\angularfire2\database.js doesn't exist
>         .ts
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           [myPath]\angularfire2\database.ts doesn't exist
>         as directory
>           [myPath]\angularfire2\database doesn't exist
>   [[myPath]\angularfire2\database]
>   [[myPath]\angularfire2\database.js]
>   [[myPath]\angularfire2\database.ts]
>   [[myPath]\angularfire2\database]
>    @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 29:0-56
>    @ ./src/app/main.ts

The app works fine when testing locally or in the lab.

Am I missing dependencies for a production build?

Answer (score 1):

**you try rolled back version**

> AngularFire 4.0.0-rc.1 does not seem to have this issue, 4.0.0-rc.2
>   does. I rolled back for now.